# What is the "minimal" structure in which points and lines are defined?

Tags: geometry, definition

Points, straight lines and planes are fundamental concept of geometry. 
Usually this entities are defined in a structure. We can easily define points in a vector space, or in a affine or projective space, but in this case what we define really is the structure of such spaces, of which points are elements and line are subspaces of subvarieties. So they are not defined  for themselves, but only by means of the structure of which they are elements.

Also in a purely geometric approach, we know that they cannot be defined for themselves, but only by means of axioms that give meaning to such undefined primitives things. A classical way to do this is, e.g., by means of the axioms of Hilbert in his ''Foundations of Geometry'' where points, lines and planes are introduced as primitive undefined elements.

A way to eliminate the words ''point'' and ''line'' from the definitions is to use as structure a [lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)), i.e. a partially ordered set in which any two elements have a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound. This is the approach of Menger and Birkhoff for the definition of projective geometries.
Von Neumann showed that we can have lattices where there are no points or lines or planes ([continous geometries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_geometry)) that generalize the projective geometries.

So it seams that for a good definition of the concept of ''point'' (and straight line) the more simple structure that we can use is a lattice. In some sense, points become well defined mathematical entities only if we have an order relation with suitable properties.

My question is: lattices are really the most simple structure that we need for define points, and what are exactly the properties that a structure must have for define points ( and straight lines and planes)?

Comment: I think you want Hilbert's treatment of geometry. I recommend Hartshorne, Geometry: Euclid and Beyond. Projective geometry is another matter, you can just call one set of things points and one set of things lines and demand certain relations; I guess you know that much already. Anyway, Hilbert's approach is quite minimalist and axiomatic, in particular synthetic, and Hartshorne is faithful to that.

Comment: Another book on the same subject is Marvin Greenberg's "Euclidian and non-euclidian geometries"

Comment: @Arthur: I haw a Marvin book that terminate at pag 471.

Comment: Anyway, it seems to me that points and lines in this book are undefined terms ( pag. 12).

Comment: Are you asking for an (at least partial) order of mathematical structures, in terms of “simplicity” or “minimality”? I fear that this might make the question rather vague unless you can give precise meaning to this. For example, I personally consider the Fano plane to be far simpler than a lattice. I think get your point about why you consider lattices to be more basic here, but I wouldn't be able to compare any other structure along the same lines, simply because those “same lines” are not spelled out so I don't trust my understanding of them.

Comment: @MvG: I realize that my question is not well defined. And I do not know the Fano plane ( has a finite number of points if I remember). What I mean by '' simpler structure '' refers to both the number  of operations in the structure that the number of axioms needed to define it. in this sense a lattice is more simple than a vector space or a ring. (we can build a ring  from a projective geometry).

Comment: @EmilioNovati: The [Fano plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) is the projective plane over the finite field of order $2$. With 7 points and 7 lines it is as small as projective planes get. I.e. if you use axioms and undefined terms, that's the smallest model. If you build on a vector space, $\mathbb Z_2$ is the smallest field you can use. Or you can simply enumerate all the items and incidences and thus build the plane directly from set theoretic machinery. Perhaps using the fact that $\mathbb Z_2$ arithmetic and boolean algebra are almost the same.

Comment: see also http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/old-and-new-results-in-the-foundations-of-elementary-plane-euclidean-and-non-euclidean-geometries  in the middle it says Read The Article and you can download the article by clicking on that.

Comment: @WillJagy: Thank you. It seems very interesting. I've also found an old paper (http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/86390?sid=21106153605463&uid=60&uid=2479680087&uid=3738296&uid=3&uid=2) of Von Neumann where the condition for existence of points in a lattice is clarified. It seems that lattices are the natural structures for define a geometry.